# How to change enum definition without impacting clients using it in C#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have the following enum defined. I have used underscores as this enum is used in logging and i don't want to incur the overhead of reflection by using custom attribute.We use very heavy logging. Now requirement is to change "LoginFailed_InvalidAttempt1" to  "LoginFailed Attempt1". If i change this enum, i will have to change its value across application. I can replace underscore by a space inside logging SP. Is there any way by which i can change this without affecting whole application.Please suggest.

```
public enum ActionType
{
    None,
    Created,
    Modified,
    Activated,
    Inactivated,
    Deleted,
    Login,
    Logout,
    ChangePassword,
    ResetPassword,
    InvalidPassword,
    LoginFailed_LockedAccount,
    LoginFailed_InActiveAccount,
    LoginFailed_ExpiredAccount,
    ForgotPassword,
    LoginFailed_LockedAccount_InvalidAttempts,
    LoginFailed_InvalidAttempt1,
    LoginFailed_InvalidAttempt2,
    LoginFailed_InvalidAttempt3,
    ForgotPassword_InvalidAttempt1,
    ForgotPassword_InvalidAttempt2,
    ForgotPassword_InvalidAttempt3,
    SessionTimeOut,
    ForgotPassword_LockedAccount,
    LockedAccount,
    ReLogin,
    ChangePassword_Due_To_Expiration,
    ChangePassword_AutoExpired

}
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to output a friendly enum name in place of the enum? Or are you saying you want to replace the actual enum name with an enum with a space in it's name?

Comment: i want to convert LoginFailed_InvalidAttempt1 to Login Failed Attempt1

Comment: .. What do you mean by convert from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to do it will be with a Description attribute. I understand that you don't use reflection, but you can always cache the result so it only happens once?

Add the description attribute:

```
[Description("LoginFailed Attempt1")]
LoginFailed_InvalidAttempt1
```

Then when displaying the text value of the enum, you can get the description out using the following bit of code:

```
private static Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Enum, string>> enumMaps = null;

public static string GetDescription(Enum value)
{
    Type eType = value.GetType();
    if (enumMaps == null)
    {
        enumMaps = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Enum, string>> ();
    }
    Dictionary<Enum, string> map;
    if (enumMaps.ContainsKey(eType))
    {
        map = enumMaps[eType];
    }
    else
    {
        map = new Dictionary<Enum, string>();
        foreach (Enum e in Enum.GetValues(eType))
        {
            FieldInfo fi = eType.GetField(e.ToString());
            DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
                typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            map[e] = (attributes.Length > 0) ? attributes[0].Description : e.ToString();
        }
        enumMaps[eType] = map;
    }
    return map[value];
}
```

As you can see from the code above, the reflection is only done **once**. Any subsequent calls on the same Enum value will return the result from a `Dictionary` which is lightning fast.

Comment: @Rohit, the descriptions are reflected on just the first time (that's the slow part), after that, the result is from a dictionary, so it's very fast. I think this would solve your problem.

Comment: yes,its lightning fast except first time.thanks for such a great piece of code.It actually helps us to do a lot of things differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can make two enum values have the same integer number, and mark one obsolete:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    Value1,
    Value2,

    [Obsolete]
    Value3,

    NewValue3 = Value3,
}
```

so then `MyEnum.Value3 == MyEnum.NewValue3`

Comment: How does this help? The way I read it is that the OP wants to be able to output "LoginFailed Attempt1" in place of "LoginFailed_InvalidAttempt1". As you cannot put spaces within an Enum name, I don't see how this solves the problem? Or I might be mistaken.

Comment: MyEnum testValue = MyEnum.NewValue3;
When you query "testValue" you get Value3, not "NewValue3"

However you could add NewValue3 immediately after Value2 which would resolve this.

Comment: Swap round the new values then - obsolete values go at the end of the enum definition